# Laravel route model binding for model with UUID does not instantiate the model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-models

I've run out of ideas, so I thought I'll ask around. Here's my code:

```php
# app/Map/MapServiceProvider.php

class MapServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any package services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Route::model('map_marker', Marker::class);

        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/Migrations');
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes.php');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Provider added to the `app.php`

```php
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
    // ...
    App\Map\MapServiceProvider::class,
])->toArray(),
```

```php
# app/Map/routes.php

use App\Map\Controllers\UpdateMarkerController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::put('/marker/{map_marker}', UpdateMarkerController::class)
    ->whereUuid('map_marker');
// ...
```

```php
# app/Map/Migrations/.._create_map_markers_table.php

Schema::create('map_markers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->double('lat');
    $table->double('lng');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```php
# app/Map/Models/Marker.php

class Marker extends Model
{
    use HasUuids;

    protected $table = 'map_markers';

    protected $fillable = ['lat', 'lng'];
}
```

The model does not seem to resolve. I'm getting an empty model when injected to the controller's *invoke* method:

```php
# app/Map/Controllers/UpdateMarkerController.php

class UpdateMarkerController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Marker $marker): JsonResponse
    {
        dd($marker);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
App\Map\Models\Marker {#285 // app/Map/Controllers/UpdateMarkerController.php:21
  #connection: null
  #table: "map_markers"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:2 [
    0 => "lat"
    1 => "lng"
  ]
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

When I try to pull it directly from the router:

```php
# app/Map/Controllers/UpdateMarkerController.php

class UpdateMarkerController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        dd($request->route('map_marker'));
    }
}
```

I get just the value of the bound segment:

```
"9a783cd6-3e87-49b8-b392-e1bb8be45521"
```

I'm sure I must be missing something simple.

Comment: whats the primary key name? by default a model is bound with the value into the primary key of that table. Something like `Model::find($request->route('segment'))`

Comment: it's just `id` - sorry I'll add migration too.

Comment: can you put on your routes theis on the param? `{map_marker:id}`

Comment: I did try this already without any luck.

Comment: It could be something between `id` and `uuid`. Add these to model: `protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';protected $keyType = 'string';public $incrementing = false;`

Comment: All this is already covered by the `HasUuid` trait - my primary key name is `id` as stated in the migration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the route. It should have the same name as your model name.

Try to use:

```
Route::put('/marker/{marker}', UpdateMarkerController::class)
```

Your model will pick it up after this.

Also `whereUuid` is not needed for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There's definitely a `whereUuid` route function. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/85a514632e410ae8f90c2b32c79a2788ba9d1076/src/Illuminate/Routing/CreatesRegularExpressionRouteConstraints.php#L59

Comment: I edited my post, you are right. I thought this package was used:
https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-model-uuid

Comment: Thanks, however I'm using explicit binding - what you're suggesting is implicit and I did try this as well without any luck (removing binding from the service provider as implicit bindings are working without explicitly specifying the way model is being put together). I'm using `whereUuid`  to ensure it actually is passing the parameter in the correct format and it doesn't affect anything in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there might be an issue with the model binding for your Marker model in the UpdateMarkerController. Let's take a look at your code and see if we can identify the problem.

Make sure that the route parameter in your route definition in routes.php is named correctly. In your code, you have specified the parameter as map_marker:

```
Route::put('/marker/{map_marker}', UpdateMarkerController::class)
    ->whereUuid('map_marker');
```

In your UpdateMarkerController, you should type-hint the parameter name to match the route parameter:

```
public function __invoke(Marker $map_marker): JsonResponse 
{
    dd($map_marker);
}
```

By doing this, Laravel should automatically resolve the Marker model using the map_marker route parameter.

Ensure that your Marker model uses the HasUuids trait correctly, and the UUID is stored as the primary key in the database. Based on your migration, it appears to be set up correctly.
If you've checked all of the above and it's still not working, here are some additional troubleshooting steps:

Make sure that you have imported the Marker model at the top of your UpdateMarkerController file using use App\Map\Models\Marker;.

Verify that there are no typos or naming discrepancies in your model, controller, and route definitions.

Clear the route cache by running php artisan route:clear to make sure any changes to your routes are picked up.

Ensure that the UUID value you're passing in the route matches an existing record in your database.

Comment: Nope, none if this makes any difference and everything is imported correctly etc. - thanks though.

Comment: @ThinkICanCode - Please make sure to read and follow our [Current policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) - We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by posting your own quality questions and answers in the future.  Thanks!